# Convert JSON empty array to empty string

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jquery-selectors

I have some JSON that looks like this:

```
{
                "ST": "Security",
                "C1": "Login failures",
                "C2": "1",
                "C3": {},
                "P1": "2",
                "P2": "administrator",
                "P3": {},
                "P4": {},
                "DESCR": "failed login attempts",
                "SID": "88",
                "AV": "NO",
                "SC": "0",
                "CN": {}
            }
```

I also have this jQuery loop to filter out values:

```
$.each(data, function(key, value) {
    var innerArr = [];
    $.each(value, function(innerKey, innerValue) {
        innerArr.push(innerValue);
    });
    valueArr.push(innerArr);
});
```

The problem is that on items C3, P3, P4 & CN in my example, the each loop is pushing the value `[object Object]` into my value collection.

Is there a way to make these items empty strings rather than objects?

Comment: in fact, it's not `empty JSON array` but `empty JSON object`, difference is in brackets `[]`(array), `{}`(object)

Comment: In JSON, an array is represented by `["value0", "value1"]` and an object by `{"key0": "value0", "key1": "value1"}` http://www.json.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use:

```
...
if(typeof innerValue == "object") innerValue = JSON.stringify(innerValue);
valueArr.push(innerValue);
....
```

The `stringify` method of the `JSON` object turns an object into a string. The empty object `{}` will turn in `"{}"`. If you want to add an empty string instead, use:

```
if(typeof innerValue == "object"){
    innerValue = JSON.stringify(innerValue);
    if(innerValue == "{}") innerValue = "";
}
valueArr.push(innerValue);
```

If you're 100% sure that your object is empty, you don't have to use `JSON.stringify`. `typeof innerValue == "onject"` would then be sufficient, to check whether you have to add `""` instead of `innerValue`.

An alternative method to check whether an object is empty or not:

```
if(typeof innerValue == "object"){
    var isEmpty = true;
    for(var i in innerValue){
        isEmpty = false;
        break;
    }
    if(isEmpty) innerValue = "";
    else {
        //Object not empty, consider JSON.stringify
    }
}
valueArr.push(innerValue);
```

Comment: Will this also work? 
`if (!innerValue) { innerArr.push(innerValue); }`

Comment: An object will always evaluate to true. Non-empty strings, and integers != 0 will also evaluate to true. In short, your proposal won't work.

Comment: Using `JSON.stringfy`, you will *only* see `[object Object]` if a string has this content. Can you show an example where `[object Object]` shows up?

Answer (score 1):

```
$.each(data, function(key, value) {
    var innerArr = [];
    $.each(value, function(innerKey, innerValue) {
        if (typeof innerValue == 'object') {
            innerValue = '';
        }
        innerArr.push(innerValue);
    });
    valueArr.push(innerArr);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

FYI, you can use **.parseJSON** function and get results easily

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON('{"ST":"Security"}');
alert( obj.ST === "Security" );
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$.each(data, function(key, value) {
    var innerArr = [];
    $.each(value, function(innerKey, innerValue) {
        innerValue = ($.isEmptyObject(innerValue)) ? '' : innerValue;
        innerArr.push(innerValue);
    });
    valueArr.push(innerArr);
});
```

---

**Edit:**

If you didn't want to rely on jQuery's `isEmptyObject()` function, you could [implement one yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5223/length-of-javascript-associative-array/6700#6700):

```
Object.size = function(obj) {
    var size = 0, key;
    for (key in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) size++;
    }
    return size;
};

// Get the size of an object
var size = Object.size(myArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the inside loop for? It loops on each single letter of the String values.

```
$.each(data, function(key, value) {
    var innerArr = [];
    if (jQuery.isEmptyObject(value)) {
        value = '';
    }
    ...
});
```

Anyway you can use [jQuery.isEmptyObject](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.isEmptyObject/)() to test easily if value is an empty object and modify it to an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.each(data, function(key, value) {
    var innerArr = [];
    $.each(value, function(innerKey, innerValue) {
        innerArr.push(innerValue);
    });
    //valueArr.push(innerArr);
    valueArr.push(innerArr.join());
});
```